# How to receive command line argument in shell script for loop

Tags: shell, for-loop

How to receive command line argument in shell script `for` loop? e.g

```
vim batch_echo  
for i in {1..$1}; do echo $i; done

sh batch_echo 3
{1..3}
```

but if change to `seq`, it's ok

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`; do echo $i; done

sh batch_echo 3
1
2
3
```

so why `{1..$1}` cannot work?

Comment: That's the hammer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just like bash, I think it's because brace expansion occurs before expansion of variables.
I recommend you to go check: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion . Let me know if that helped or not.

Hope I could help.